# Apache Mod Rewrite rules giving 404 error - trying to use to create web api

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, asp.net-web-api

I am using apache mod rewrite to redirect all urls in the api subdirectory to the controller at index.php:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

All api calls will also have to be to the https hence the server port line. However, when I test this out, I am getting a 404 page error...

Anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be the case?

-Sneha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options -Multiviews
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^/api/([^/]+)/?$ /api/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```